# How JPA works with Oracle ROWNUM

Tags: java, oracle

JPA setFirstResult does always point to ROWNUM value 1, or the first record in a result set with different ROWNUM value ? and accrodingly how setMaxResults works?

Comment: `setFirstResult` and `setMaxResults` are used for pagination in jpa. If you want first ten rows you write: `setFirstResult(0)` and `setMaxResults(10)`. For second ten rows : `setFirstResult(10)` and `setMaxResults(10)`. And so on

Comment: As for oracle they will use `ROWNUM` syntax

Comment: Due to issue in our query, I am getting results with ROWNUM value in an incorrect order, like below
91
90
89
88
87
86
85
84
6
83
82
instead of 1,2,3,4,5,6 and so. Now on this resultset , if I use JPA
setFirstResult(0)
setMaxResults(6)

what will be the final resultset, Shall I get 6 records from 91 to 86 (which is not properly ordered) or will get records in different order?